# Como colocar 'ws:' somente no primeiro nó do xml de um request de um servico WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Tenho uma aplicação WCF que possui um serviço veiculo.svc como na figura 1. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No serviço veiculo.svc tem um método registrar que recebe um DTO veiculoDto como na figura 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class VeiculoDto
{
    public string AnoFabricacao { get; set; }
    public string AnoModelo { get; set; }
    public string Placa { get; set; }
}
```

Por sua vez o serviço Veiculo.svc implementa a interface IVeiculo.cs que possui um contrato registar como na figura 3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando o SoapUi para realizar uma chamada neste serviço tenho a seguinte requisição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O request da requisição deve ficar com a seguinte estrutura:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:ws="ws">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
     <ws:Registar>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <veiculo>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <wcf:AnoFabricacao>?</wcf:AnoFabricacao>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <wcf:AnoModelo>?</wcf:AnoModelo>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <wcf:Placa>?</wcf:Placa>
         </veiculo>
     </ws:Registar>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para que somente o nó <  Registar > fique com 'ws:' 
< ws:Registar > em sua tag?

Comment: A solução resolveu o seu problema? ou ficou faltando alguma coisa?

Answer (score 2):

> Gostaria de saber como faço para que somente o nó `<Registar>` fique
>   com 'ws:' `<ws:Registar>` em sua tag?

Sim, você pode definir que sua DTO não tenha uma namespace.
Através das propriedades do atributo `DataContract`.

Veja um exemplo:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class VeiculoDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AnoFabricacao { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AnoModelo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Placa { get; set; }
}
```

Fazendo dessa forma, o resultado será o seguinte no `SoapUI`:

[image: Resultado no SoapUI]

Você também pode remover a `namespace` do serviço, alterando as propriedades do atributo `ServiceContract`.

Exemplo:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace ="")]
public class Service
{
}
```

Unindo as duas funcionalidades, o resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado caro bruno pela ajuda! Porem quando eu utilizo ws na [DataContract(Namespace = "ws")], não sei porque todos os nós filhos também ficam com ws na sua tag, no raw do request . Gostaria que fica-se somente na tag < registar > ficando < ws: registar>.

Comment: Vou complementar a resposta

Comment: Caro bruno muito obrigador pelo complemento! Porem realizei o teste conforme o respondido e ainda continua herdando o ws para <ws: veiculo>.